# Need to prove that $|f(z)| ≤ |z^2|$ for all $z$ such that $1 ≤ |z| ≤ 2$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $A$ be the annulus in $C$ where $1 ≤ |z| ≤ 2$ for all $z$ in $A$ and let $f$ be continuous on $A$ and holomorphic on the interior of $A$.

Suppose $|f(z)| ≤  1$ if $|z| = 1$ and |$f(z)| ≤ 4$ if $|z| = 2$

Need to prove that $|f(z)| ≤ |z^2|$ for all $z \in A$.

$4$ must be an upper bound for $|f(z)|$, since $|f(z)|$ attains it's maximun on the boundary, howewer I´m kinda lost from this point.

Comment: For an inequality of the type $\lvert f(z)\rvert \leqslant \lvert g(z)\rvert$, looking at the quotient $\frac{f}{g}$ is often helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $g(z)=f(z)/z^2$. Then $f$ is holomorphic in the annulus and $\lvert g(z)\rvert\le 1$ on the boundary of the annulus.

Maximum principle implies that $\lvert g(z)\rvert< 1$, in the annulus, unless $g$ is constant.

Hence $\lvert f(z)\rvert<\lvert z\rvert^2$, unless $f(z)=cz^2$, for some constant $c$.